# морской бой на с++

Tags: c++, инспекция-кода

Недавно написал морской бой, хоть код и рабочий ,но мне кажется ,что он плохой и в нём куча ошибок. Так как я только недавно стал изучать с++ , то сам эти ошибки не увижу. Если вам не трудно , то можете дать несколько советов по этому коду. Заранее огромное спасибо.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

void field(string(&a2)[10][10], string(&b2)[10][10]) {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "                                               " << "Морской бой от valecop";
    cout << endl << endl << endl;
    //создание и заполнение таблиц
    for (int w = 0; w < 1; w++) {
        cout << "                             ";
        for (int y = 0; y < size(a2); y++) {
            cout << y << " ";
            //отвечает за столбцы первой таблицы
        }
        cout << "                   ";
        for (int y = 0; y < size(a2); y++) {
            cout << y << " ";
            //отвечает за столбцы второй таблицы
        }
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < size(a2); i++) {
            cout << "                           ";
            cout << i;
            for (int j = 0; j < size(a2); j++) {
                cout << "|" << a2[i][j];

            }
            cout << "|" << "                 ";
            cout << i;
            for (int f = 0; f < size(b2); f++) {
                cout << "|" << b2[i][f];

            }
            cout << "|" << endl;

        }
    }

}

void help(short& l, short& s, string(&a2)[10][10], string(&b2)[10][10]) {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Выберите местоположение ваших кораблей" << endl << "Корабли выставляются по возрастанию , начиная с однопалубного и заканчивая трёхпалубным" << endl;
    cout << "Введите координаты и поставьте знаки " << endl;
    cout << "Знак" << '"' << "^" << '"' << " " << "чтобы корабль стоял носом наверх\n";
    cout << "Знак" << '"' << "<" << '"' << " " << "чтобы корабль стоял носом вправо\n";
    cout << "Знак" << '"' << ">" << '"' << " " << "чтобы корабль стоял носом влево \n";
    cout << "Знак" << '"' << "!" << '"' << " " << "чтобы корабль стоял носом вниз  \n";
    cout << "введите столбик:"; cin >> l;
    cout << "введите строку: "; cin >> s;
    int tu = 10;
    while (tu != 0) {
        tu = 0;
        if (s > 9 || l > 9) {
            tu = 1;
            cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tНеверные координаты";
            Sleep(2000);
            system("cls");
            field(a2, b2);
            help(l, s, a2, b2);
        }
        else if (s < 0 || l < 0) {
            tu = 1;
            cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tНеверные координаты";
            Sleep(2000);
            system("cls");
            field(a2, b2);
            help(l, s, a2, b2);
        }

    }
}

int game(string a[10][10], string b[10][10]) {
    char t;
    short s, l;
    string a2[10][10];
    string b2[10][10];
    // заполнение масивов

    for (char i = 0; i < size(a2); i++) {
        for (char j = 0; j < size(a2); j++) {
            a2[i][j] = "?";
            b2[i][j] = "?";
            a[i][j] = "0";
            b[i][j] = "0";
        }

    }

    field(a2, b2);
    help(l, s, a2, b2);

    //расстановка корабля
    a[s][l] = "1";
    a2[s][l] = '^';

    system("cls");

    field(a2, b2);
    help(l, s, a2, b2);
    cout << "введите направление:"; cin >> t;
    //расстановка корабля
    switch (t){
    case '^' :
        if (s - 1 >= 0) {
            a[s][l] = "1";
            a2[s][l] = "O";
            a[s - 1][l] = "1";
            a2[s - 1][l] = "^";
        }
        break;
    case '>':
        if (l + 1 <= 9) {
            a[s][l] = "1";
            a2[s][l] = "O";
            a[s][l + 1] = "1";
            a2[s][l + 1] = ">";
        }
        break;
    case '<':
        if (l - 1 >= 0) {
            a[s][l] = "1";
            a2[s][l] = "O";
            a[s][l - 1] = "1";
            a2[s][l - 1] = "<";
        }
        break;
    case '!':
        if (s + 1 <= 9) {
            a[s][l] = "1";
            a2[s][l] = "O";
            a[s + 1][l] = "1";
            a2[s + 1][l] = "o";
        }
    }

    system("cls");
    field(a2, b2);
    help(l, s, a2, b2);
    cout << "введите направление:"; cin >> t;

    switch (t){
    case '^':
        if (s - 2 >= 0) {
            a[s][l] = "1";
            a2[s][l] = "O";
            a[s - 1][l] = "1";
            a2[s - 1][l] = "O";
            a[s - 2][l] = "1";
            a2[s - 2][l] = "^";
        }
        break;
    case '>':
        if (l + 2 <= 9) {
            a[s][l] = "1";
            a2[s][l] = "O";
            a[s][l + 1] = "1";
            a2[s][l + 1] = "O";
            a[s][l + 2] = "1";
            a2[s][l + 2] = ">";
        }
        break;
    case '<':
        if (l - 2 >= 0) {
            a[s][l] = "1";
            a2[s][l] = "O";
            a[s][l - 1] = "1";
            a2[s][l - 1] = "O";
            a[s][l - 2] = "1";
            a2[s][l - 2] = "<";
        }
        break;
    case '!':
        if (s + 2 <= 9) {
            a[s][l] = "1";
            a2[s][l] = "O";
            a[s + 1][l] = "1";
            a2[s + 1][l] = "O";
            a[s + 2][l] = "1";
            a2[s + 2][l] = "o";
        }

    }

    system("cls");

    field(a2, b2);

    //бот расставляет корабли
    srand(time(NULL));

    int TAB_BOT, LINE_BOT;
    TAB_BOT = rand() % 10;
    LINE_BOT = rand() % 10;
    b[TAB_BOT][LINE_BOT] = "1";
    Sleep(200);
    int u = 0;
    l = 0;
    while (u != 1) {
        TAB_BOT = rand() % 10;
        LINE_BOT = rand() % 10;

        if (TAB_BOT - 1 <= 9 && LINE_BOT - 1 <= 9) {
            if (b[TAB_BOT][LINE_BOT] != "1" && b[TAB_BOT - 1][LINE_BOT] != "1") {
                b[TAB_BOT][LINE_BOT] = "1";
                b[TAB_BOT - 1][LINE_BOT] = "1";
                u = 1;

            }
        }
    }
    Sleep(200);
    l = 0;
    while (l != 1) {
        TAB_BOT = rand() % 10;
        LINE_BOT = rand() % 10;

        if (TAB_BOT + 1 <= 9 && TAB_BOT + 2 <= 9) {
            if (b[TAB_BOT][LINE_BOT] != "1" && b[TAB_BOT + 1][LINE_BOT] != "1") {
                if (b[TAB_BOT + 2][LINE_BOT] != "1")
                    b[TAB_BOT][LINE_BOT] = "1";
                b[TAB_BOT + 1][LINE_BOT] = "1";
                b[TAB_BOT][LINE_BOT] = "1";
                b[TAB_BOT + 2][LINE_BOT] = "1";
                l++;

            }
        }
    }
    //бот закончил



    short bot_heat = 0, person_heat = 0;

    system("cls");
    while (bot_heat < 6 && person_heat < 6) {

        field(a2, b2);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Ваш ход , вбейте координаты\n";
        cout << "Введите номер столбца:"; cin >> l;
        cout << "Введите номер строки: "; cin >> s;

        if (b[s][l] == "1") {
            person_heat++;
            b2[s][l] = "*";
            cout << endl;
            cout << "вы попали";
        }
        else {
            b2[s][l] = "x";
            cout << "вы промахнулись";
        }

        system("cls");
        field(a2, b2);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "ход противника";
        Sleep(300);
        l = 1;
        while (l != 0) {
            TAB_BOT = rand() % 10;
            LINE_BOT = rand() % 10;

            if (a2[TAB_BOT][LINE_BOT] != "x" && a2[TAB_BOT][LINE_BOT] != "*") {
                if (a[TAB_BOT][LINE_BOT] == "1") {
                    bot_heat++;
                    a2[TAB_BOT][LINE_BOT] = "*";
                    l = 0;
                }
                else {
                    a2[TAB_BOT][LINE_BOT] = "x";
                    l = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        system("cls");
    }

    if (bot_heat > person_heat) {
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tБот победил!";
    }
    else {
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tВы победили!";
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    string a[10][10];
    string b[10][10];
    game(a, b);
}
```

Comment: Ваш код очень сложно понять. Именование переменных явно "хромает". Называйте переменные согласно их предназначению.

Comment: а какие "ошибки" Вы хотите? по работе или по душку кода?

Comment: koVadim,ну ,ошибки в оптимизации кода, если они там есть

Comment: ох ох. ошибки оптимизации... какой ещё оптимизации?

Comment: ну, где то за место одной части кода можно использовать что то другое ,чтобы сократить код

Comment: "сократить код" не равно "оптимизировать". Думаю, Вам нужно взять книгу Роберта Мартина "Чистый код" и она ответит на многие Ваши вопросы. Да, там много кода на java, но это почти не имеет значения.

Answer (score 2):

- Названия переменных плохие, надо переименовать
- Для массивов лучше использовать std::array
- Лучше не использовать using namespace std;
- Лучше не использовать неявные преобразования типов (в индексах,
  например)
- Вместо endl лучше использовать \n
- Вместо односимвольных строк лучше использовать символы
- Вместо множества явных пробелов для форматирования лучше использовать
  манипуляторы
- Стоит добавить обработку ошибок, а то непонятно, что вводить игроку

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin развернул

Comment: обработка ошибок это если введены неправильные координаты и ты выводишь "неверные координаты, впишите заново" ?

Answer (score 2):

В коде кроме всяких мелочей (типа endl<->\n) есть более глобальные проблемы. Начнем с мелкого, постепенно пофиксим немного.

Первое, что бросается в глаза, это вот это

```
string a[10][10];
```

после того, как присмотришься, стает понятно, что это игровое поле и a и b - это свое и противника, но абсолютно не очевидно, где чье. Сделаем первый шаг - заведем отдельный тип для этого и добавим туда пару функций.

```
class Field
{
    std::string m_field[10][10];
public:
    const std::string& get(int x, int y) { return m_field[x][y]; }
    void set(int x, int y, const std::string& v) { m_field[x][y] = x; }
};
```

этот класс просто заворачивает массив в себя. Многие на этом моменте скажут, мол, нужно уже на char поменять или использовать вектор векторов. Не нужно спешить, такое делается мелкими шагами.

Теперь в коде заиспользуем этот класс и посмотрим как оно будет.

И сразу видим в функции game вот такое

```
for (char i = 0; i < size(a2); i++) {
    for (char j = 0; j < size(a2); j++) {
        a2[i][j] = "?";
        b2[i][j] = "?";
        a[i][j] = "0";
        b[i][j] = "0";
    }

}
```

хм, так это же 4 массива заполняются символами. Более того, просто повезло, что размеры совпали удачно. Но это кандидат на отдельную функцию в Field.

А сделаем вот так

```
a2.fill("?");
b2.fill("?");
a.fill("0");
b.fill("0");
```

и соответственно

```
void fill(const std::string& el) {
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            m_field[i][j] = el;
        }
    }
}
```

да, ещё не очевидно, что значат знаки вопроса, но уже понятна суть. Двигаемся дальше по функции game.

Там вызов

```
field(a2, b2);
help(l, s, a2, b2);
```

идем в сигнатуры этих функций и меняем типы.

функция help похоже ошибок не содержит из за замены типа, а вот field не повезло. Первое - там куча `size(a2)`. Если вдруг поле станет не квадратным - все пойдет кувырком. Но и кода там намешано куча, попробуем понять, что оно делает.

Для начала нам понадобится две функции в наш класс Field

```
int get_width() const { return width; }
int get_height() const { return height; }
```

и все эти size(a2) можно поменять. правда я делал это немного наугад.

теперь настало время поменять все `a[i][j]` на `a.get(i,j)` или `a.set(i,j,...)`.

После всех замен выясняется, что да, в массиве `m_field` могут хранится только символы. И не просто символы, а только определенные символы. Заведем перечисление для этого

```
enum class CellType
{
    None,
    Type0, // 0
    Type1, // 1
    TypeQ, // ?
    TypeS, // *
    TypeO, // O
    Typeo, // o
    TypeU, // ^
    TypeL, // <
    TypeR, // >
    TypeX, // x

};
```

и функцию для вывода. Она нам ещё пригодится.

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const CellType& c)
{
    switch (c) {
    case CellType::None: os << ' '; break;
    case CellType::Type0: os << '0'; break;
    case CellType::Type1: os << '1'; break;
    case CellType::TypeQ: os << '?'; break;
    case CellType::TypeS: os << '*'; break;
    case CellType::TypeO: os << 'O'; break;
    case CellType::Typeo: os << 'o'; break;
    case CellType::TypeU: os << '^'; break;
    case CellType::TypeL: os << '<'; break;
    case CellType::TypeR: os << '>'; break;
    case CellType::TypeX: os << 'x'; break;
    }
    return os;
}
```

возникает вопрос - а почему такие странные имена? а я делал полуавтоматическую замену. я не до конца понимал суть каждого символа. Это следующий этап.

Теперь смотрим по коду и пытаемся приписать этим элементам перечисления "разумные имена".

```
enum class CellType
{
    None,
    Type0, // 0
    Ship, // 1
    TypeQ, // ?
    Hit, // *
    TypeO, // O
    BowBottom, // o
    BowUp, // ^
    BowLeft, // <
    BowRight, // >
    Miss, // x
};
```

Не все получилось, но это такое...

Теперь, если посмотреть в код, там есть ещё `system("cls")` и Sleep, который немного напрягает. Давайте сделаем для этого маленький класс

```
class Platform {
public:
    static void Init() { setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus"); }
    static void CleanScreen() { system("cls"); }
    static void Sleep(int s) { ::Sleep(s); }
};
```

На первый взгляд он выглядит странно, но на самом деле он инкапсулировал в себе все платформенно зависимое. И теперь вместе с `#include <Windows.h>` можно унести в отдельный файл. Потом, позже, чуточку переделав, можно сделать этот код рабочим и под Linux/Mac или ncurce. Мелочь, а приятно.

Попутно выясняется, что функция `field` скорее всего должна называться `show_field`. Функция help на самом деле не только показывает подсказу, а и спрашивает координаты удара. `get_user_input`? `ask_user_about_coord`?. А по хорошему ее нужно ещё и разделить на несколько меньших.

Да, мы подобрались к самому вкусному. Функция `game` - она на самом деле огромная. Она должна быть порезана на куски. Более того, комментарии внутри намекают на это.

Смотрим на это

```
get_user_input(l, s, a2, b2);
cout << "введите направление:"; cin >> t;
```

ой ой. мы получили координаты, а потом ещё прямо запрашиваем направление и чуть ниже заполняем наши поля.  И посмотрев на это по новому, я понял, что это просто запрос одного однопалубного, одного двух палубного и одного трехпалубного. Неочевиденько.

В процессе выделения выясняется, что там есть прям готовая функция

```
void generate_bot_ships(Field& b)
```

о, значит `b` - это все таки от бот, а `a` - это игрок.

Я также заметил, что очень часто одни и теже переменные используются для разных целей. Не нужно боятся делать разные переменные для разных целей. одной такой есть переменная с именем `l`, которая и для пользовательского ввода используется, и для флажков.

Пока получилось уже так

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class Platform {
public:
    static void Init() { setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus"); }
    static void CleanScreen() { system("cls"); }
    static void Sleep(int s) { ::Sleep(s); }
};


enum class CellType
{
    None,
    Type0, // 0
    Ship, // 1
    TypeQ, // ?
    Hit, // *
    TypeO, // O
    BowBottom, // o
    BowUp, // ^
    BowLeft, // <
    BowRight, // >
    Miss, // x

};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const CellType& c)
{
    switch (c) {
    case CellType::None: os << ' '; break;
    case CellType::Type0: os << '0'; break;
    case CellType::Ship: os << '1'; break;
    case CellType::TypeQ: os << '?'; break;
    case CellType::Hit: os << '*'; break;
    case CellType::TypeO: os << 'O'; break;
    case CellType::BowBottom: os << 'o'; break;
    case CellType::BowUp: os << '^'; break;
    case CellType::BowLeft: os << '<'; break;
    case CellType::BowRight: os << '>'; break;
    case CellType::Miss: os << 'x'; break;
    }
    return os;
}

class Field
{
    static const int width = 10;
    static const int height = 10;
    CellType m_field[width][height];
public:
    const CellType get(int x, int y) { return m_field[x][y]; }
    void set(int x, int y, const CellType v) { m_field[x][y] = v; }
    void fill(const CellType el) {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                m_field[i][j] = el;
            }
        }
    }
    int get_width() const { return width; }
    int get_height() const { return height; }
};

void show_field(Field& a2, Field& b2) {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "                                               " << "Морской бой от valecop";
    cout << endl << endl << endl;
    //создание и заполнение таблиц
    for (int w = 0; w < 1; w++) {
        cout << "                             ";
        for (int y = 0; y < a2.get_width(); y++) {
            cout << y << " ";
            //отвечает за столбцы первой таблицы
        }
        cout << "                   ";
        for (int y = 0; y < a2.get_width(); y++) { // 2? b2?
            cout << y << " ";
            //отвечает за столбцы второй таблицы
        }
        cout << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < a2.get_width(); i++) {
            cout << "                           ";
            cout << i;
            for (int j = 0; j < a2.get_width(); j++) {
                cout << "|" << a2.get(i,j);
            }
            cout << "|" << "                 ";
            cout << i;
            for (int f = 0; f < b2.get_width(); f++) {
                cout << "|" << b2.get(i,f);
            }
            cout << "|" << endl;
        }
    }
}

void get_user_input(short& l, short& s, Field& a2, Field& b2) {
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Выберите местоположение ваших кораблей" << endl << "Корабли выставляются по возрастанию , начиная с однопалубного и заканчивая трёхпалубным" << endl;
    cout << "Введите координаты и поставьте знаки " << endl;
    cout << "Знак" << '"' << CellType::BowUp << '"' << " " << "чтобы корабль стоял носом наверх\n";
    cout << "Знак" << '"' << CellType::BowLeft << '"' << " " << "чтобы корабль стоял носом вправо\n";
    cout << "Знак" << '"' << CellType::BowRight << '"' << " " << "чтобы корабль стоял носом влево \n";
    cout << "Знак" << '"' << "!" << '"' << " " << "чтобы корабль стоял носом вниз  \n";
    cout << "введите столбик:"; cin >> l;
    cout << "введите строку: "; cin >> s;
    int tu = 10;
    while (tu != 0) {
        tu = 0;
        if (s > 9 || l > 9) {
            tu = 1;
            cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tНеверные координаты";
            Platform::Sleep(2000);
            Platform::CleanScreen();
            show_field(a2, b2);
            get_user_input(l, s, a2, b2);
        }
        else if (s < 0 || l < 0) {
            tu = 1;
            cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tНеверные координаты";
            Platform::Sleep(2000);
            Platform::CleanScreen();
            show_field(a2, b2);
            get_user_input(l, s, a2, b2);
        }
    }
}

void ask_user_about_initial_ships(Field& a2, Field& b2, Field& a)
{
    char t;
    short s, l;
    show_field(a2, b2);
    get_user_input(l, s, a2, b2);

    //расстановка корабля
    a.set(s, l, CellType::Ship);
    a2.set(s, l, CellType::BowUp);

    Platform::CleanScreen();

    show_field(a2, b2);
    get_user_input(l, s, a2, b2);
    cout << "введите направление:"; cin >> t;
    //расстановка корабля
    switch (t) {
    case '^':
        if (s - 1 >= 0) {
            a.set(s, l, CellType::Ship);
            a2.set(s, l, CellType::TypeO);
            a.set(s - 1, l, CellType::Ship);
            a2.set(s - 1, l, CellType::BowUp);

        }
        break;
    case '>':
        if (l + 1 <= 9) {
            a.set(s, l, CellType::Ship);
            a2.set(s, l, CellType::TypeO);
            a.set(s + 1, l, CellType::Ship);
            a2.set(s + 1, l, CellType::BowRight);
        }
        break;
    case '<':
        if (l - 1 >= 0) {
            a.set(s, l, CellType::Ship);
            a2.set(s, l, CellType::TypeO);
            a.set(s, l - 1, CellType::Ship);
            a2.set(s, l - 1, CellType::BowLeft);
        }
        break;
    case '!':
        if (s + 1 <= 9) {
            a.set(s, l, CellType::Ship);
            a2.set(s, l, CellType::TypeO);
            a.set(s + 1, l, CellType::Ship);
            a2.set(s + 1, l, CellType::BowBottom);
        }
    }

    Platform::CleanScreen();
    show_field(a2, b2);
    get_user_input(l, s, a2, b2);
    cout << "введите направление:"; cin >> t;

    switch (t) {
    case '^':
        if (s - 2 >= 0) {
            a.set(s, l, CellType::Ship);
            a2.set(s, l, CellType::TypeO);
            a.set(s - 1, l, CellType::Ship);
            a2.set(s - 1, l, CellType::TypeO);
            a.set(s - 2, l, CellType::Ship);
            a2.set(s - 2, l, CellType::BowUp);
        }
        break;
    case '>':
        if (l + 2 <= 9) {
            a.set(s, l, CellType::Ship);
            a2.set(s, l, CellType::TypeO);
            a.set(s, l + 1, CellType::Ship);
            a2.set(s, l + 1, CellType::TypeO);
            a.set(s, l + 2, CellType::Ship);
            a2.set(s, l + 2, CellType::BowRight);
        }
        break;
    case '<':
        if (l - 2 >= 0) {
            a.set(s, l, CellType::Ship);
            a2.set(s, l, CellType::TypeO);
            a.set(s, l - 1, CellType::Ship);
            a2.set(s, l - 1, CellType::TypeO);
            a.set(s, l - 2, CellType::Ship);
            a2.set(s, l - 2, CellType::BowLeft);
        }
        break;
    case '!':
        if (s + 2 <= 9) {
            a.set(s, l, CellType::Ship);
            a2.set(s, l, CellType::TypeO);
            a.set(s + 1, l, CellType::Ship);
            a2.set(s + 1, l, CellType::TypeO);
            a.set(s + 2, l, CellType::Ship);
            a2.set(s + 2, l, CellType::BowBottom);
        }

    }
}

void generate_bot_ships(Field& b)
{
    short l;
    //бот расставляет корабли
    srand(time(NULL));

    int TAB_BOT = rand() % 10;
    int LINE_BOT = rand() % 10;
    b.set(TAB_BOT, LINE_BOT, CellType::Ship);
    Platform::Sleep(200);
    int u = 0;
    l = 0;
    while (u != 1) {
        TAB_BOT = rand() % 10;
        LINE_BOT = rand() % 10;

        if (TAB_BOT - 1 <= 9 && LINE_BOT - 1 <= 9) {
            if (b.get(TAB_BOT, LINE_BOT) != CellType::Ship && b.get(TAB_BOT - 1, LINE_BOT) != CellType::Ship) {
                b.set(TAB_BOT, LINE_BOT, CellType::Ship);
                b.set(TAB_BOT - 1, LINE_BOT, CellType::Ship);
                u = 1;

            }
        }
    }
    Platform::Sleep(200);
    l = 0;
    while (l != 1) {
        TAB_BOT = rand() % 10;
        LINE_BOT = rand() % 10;

        if (TAB_BOT + 1 <= 9 && TAB_BOT + 2 <= 9) {
            if (b.get(TAB_BOT, LINE_BOT) != CellType::Ship && b.get(TAB_BOT + 1, LINE_BOT) != CellType::Ship) {
                if (b.get(TAB_BOT + 2, LINE_BOT) != CellType::Ship)
                    b.set(TAB_BOT, LINE_BOT, CellType::Ship);
                b.set(TAB_BOT + 1, LINE_BOT, CellType::Ship);
                b.set(TAB_BOT, LINE_BOT, CellType::Ship);
                b.set(TAB_BOT + 2, LINE_BOT, CellType::Ship);
                l++;

            }
        }
    }
    //бот закончил
}

int game(Field a, Field b) {
    //char t;
    short s, l;
    Field a2{};
    Field b2{};
    // заполнение масивов
    a2.fill(CellType::TypeQ);
    b2.fill(CellType::TypeQ);
    a.fill(CellType::Type0);
    b.fill(CellType::Type0);

    ask_user_about_initial_ships(a2, b2, a);

    Platform::CleanScreen();

    show_field(a2, b2);

    generate_bot_ships(b);
    short bot_heat = 0, person_heat = 0;

    Platform::CleanScreen();
    while (bot_heat < 6 && person_heat < 6) {
        show_field(a2, b2);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Ваш ход , вбейте координаты\n";
        cout << "Введите номер столбца:"; cin >> l;
        cout << "Введите номер строки: "; cin >> s;

        if (b.get(s,l) == CellType::Ship) {
            person_heat++;
            b2.set(s,l, CellType::Hit);
            cout << endl;
            cout << "вы попали";
        }
        else {
            b2.set(s,l, CellType::Miss);
            cout << "вы промахнулись";
        }

        Platform::CleanScreen();
        show_field(a2, b2);
        cout << endl;
        cout << "ход противника";
        Platform::Sleep(300);
        bool need_to_continue = false;
        while (need_to_continue) {
            int TAB_BOT = rand() % 10;
            int LINE_BOT = rand() % 10;

            if (a2.get(TAB_BOT,LINE_BOT) != CellType::Miss && a2.get(TAB_BOT,LINE_BOT) != CellType::Hit) {
                if (a.get(TAB_BOT,LINE_BOT) == CellType::Ship) {
                    bot_heat++;
                    a2.set(TAB_BOT,LINE_BOT, CellType::Hit);
                }
                else {
                    a2.set(TAB_BOT,LINE_BOT, CellType::Miss);
                }
                need_to_continue = true;
            }
        }
        Platform::CleanScreen();
    }

    if (bot_heat > person_heat) {
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tБот победил!";
    }
    else {
        cout << "\t\t\t\t\t\tВы победили!";
    }
    return 0;
}


int main() {
    Platform::Init();
    Field a{};
    Field b{};
    game(a, b);
}
```

Но тут ещё работать и работать, а у меня есть и своя работа.

Comment: спасибо но можете объяснить эту функцию

Comment: какую именно функцию?

Comment: std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const CellType& c)
{
    switch (c) {
    case CellType::None: os << ' '; break;
    case CellType::Type0: os << '0'; break;
    case CellType::Type1: os << '1'; break;
    case CellType::TypeQ: os << '?'; break;
    case CellType::TypeS: os << '*'; break;
    case CellType::TypeO: os << 'O'; break;
    case CellType::Typeo: os << 'o'; break;
    case CellType::TypeU: os << '^'; break;
    case CellType::TypeL: os << '<'; break;
    case CellType::TypeR: os << '>'; break;
    case CellType::TypeX: os << 'x'; break;
    }
  return os;
}

Comment: функция вывода.

Comment: если мы пытаемся вывести в cout какой-нибудь тип, который тот не понимает, то нужно написать вот такую странную функцию, которая как раз будет "преобразовывать" объект в текстовое представление. Я собственно энум преобразовываю в текст. И теперь, в справке я распечатываю не символ, а значение нужного энума. И если вдруг решите использовать другой символ, его нужно будет поменять в одном (и только одном!!!) месте.

Comment: ясно, спасибо за объяснение